# amazon S3 bucket level stats

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, statistics, bucket

I'd like to know if there's a way for me to have bucket-level stats in amazon s3.
Basically i want to charge customers for storage and GET requests on my system (which is hosted on s3).

So i created a specific bucket for each client, but i can't seem to get the stats just for a specific bucket.

I see the API lets me

```
GET Bucket
```

or

```
GET Bucket requestPayment
```

But i just can't find how to get the number of requests issued to said bucket and the total size of the bucket.

Thanks for help !

Regards

Comment: One alternative which may be of interest, is to create a new AWS account (thus benefiting from the free tier) and add it alongside an existing account, via consolidated billing. Then all stats/logs etc are tied solely to that account. Naturally if you already have a large setup and whatnot then this may not be simple - thought I would put it out there anyway :)

Comment: That was my initial thought but i'm going to have dozens of clients to handle simultaneously. So this solution is not the right one for my specific issue.Thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that what you are trying to achieve is possible using Amazon API. The [GET Bucket request](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html) does not contain usage statistics (requests, etc) other than the timestamp of the latest modification (`LastModified`).

My suggestion would be that you enable logging in your buckets and perform the analysis that you want from there.

[S3 starting page](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) gives you an overview on it:

> Amazon S3 also supports logging of requests made against your Amazon S3 resources. You can configure your Amazon S3 bucket to create access log records for the requests made against it. These server access logs capture all requests made against a bucket or the objects in it and can be used for auditing purposes.

And I am sure there is plenty of documentation on that matter.
HTH.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that, this seems to be the right way to go !